# Timing a list if bullet points in Kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive

I have a list of bullet points that I'd like to hide and then display one after another with a 1 second delay between each.

Is a simple way to do this in Kdenlive? The only way I can see is to create a separate title clip for each point, carefully align the text in each clip, and then set a transparency effect for each clip, but that's a ton of work for a relatively simple visual.